# How to get coordinates of multi-line span element?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, dom, vuejs3

I'd think this would be simple/common but can't find it anywhere after months of looking. I would like to edit segments of a paragraph but have the input element overlay on the section being edited. Y coordinates are easy, but to get where the span element is when it goes into a second line, it gives me the left offset of the second line instead of the first -- and I understand the logic of why. But what convoluted mind-numbing method can I use to get the position of the first line?

```
let strings = [
    'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ...{{ autogenerated Lorem Ipsum }}
              ];

strings = strings.map((str) => str.replace(/(\.|\?|\!)/g, '$1 |||'));
<template>
<p>
   <span v-for="(content, index) in strings"></span></p></template>
```

Yes, it's Vue3 but it doesn't really matter to the question. And the code that I'm trying right now has a whole bunch of ref(null) etc so I'm just skipping all that. I'm just trying

```
target.getBoundingClientRect().left // target.getBoundingClientRect().x is the same
```

**How can I get the x position of where my span element begins?**

Comment: Why do you need this? I'd imagine there is a much more elegant solution to whatever it is your trying to achieve here. "Position" is rarely useful if your markup, etc. is structured correctly. You should be thinking more responsively

Comment: What you need is `getClientRects()`, not `getBoundingClientRect()`.

Comment: @Alohci thanks! Wow, I can't believe that's a thing! it wasn't in any of the suggested code, might be because I always stopped at getClientRect() and that returned an error.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [offsetLeft](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetLeft)

> for inline-level elements (such as span) that can wrap from one line to the next, offsetTop and offsetLeft describe the positions of the first border box (use Element.getClientRects() to get its width and height

therefor,

```js
target.offsetLeft
```

will return the x position of where your target (span) element begins

Comment: Thats awesome! thanks.... even after reading your answer though, my brain didn't want to go in that direction... I kept trying leftOffset, oy...